# Shape of a set in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be biholomorphic function and $D$ be a simply connected domain.Is $ f(\partial D) -f(\partial D)$ topologically equivalent to $D$? By $ f(\partial D) -f(\partial D)$ I mean
$ \{z\mid z_1-z_2,z_1,z_2\text{ lie on } {\partial D}\}$

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out.I made an edit

Comment: In a simple case: $D$ is the open unit disk, $f$ is the identity, and $f(\partial D) -f(\partial D)$ is a closed disk of radius $2$?

Comment: where is $f$ defined? is it defined on $D$, on the closure $\overline{D}$, or on an open set containing $\overline{D}$? in the first case, $f(\partial D)$ is not defined. in the second case, what do you mean by $f$ is a biholomorphism?